# Animating a curve in Maya with Python

Tags: python, maya, maya-api

I am doing a keyframe scripted physics animation in Maya (with Python) and I want to show some vectors (results of the algorithm) that affect the animated objects.

To represent a vector I chose a curve:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
vectorCurve = cmds.curve(d=1, p=[(x, y, z), (p, q, r)])
```

Then, when creating the keyframes for the animation, I do:

```
for i in range(300):
    #a,b,c,d,e,f values change every iteration
    cmds.move(a, b, c, vectorCurve + ".ep[0]", wd=True)
    cmds.move(d, e, f, vectorCurve + ".ep[1]", wd=True)

    cmds.setKeyframe(vectorCurve, time=i)
```

But when I run the script, the curves stay in their final position and do not move during the animation.

How could I set the animation keyframes for a (linear) curve correctly?

EDIT:
The curve actually has keyframes, but when I look into the keyed values in Channel Box, translate and rotate are all 0 and scale is 1 (for X, Y and Z).

Comment: I don't think you can animate straight on Edit Points, but you can probably bind them to a cluster handle, then animate this cluster?

Edit: Could be worth trying `setKeyframe` with `controlPoints=True`, I'm not sure. Standard is definitely just TRS

Comment: @itypewithmyhands I added `controlPoints=True` to `setKeyframe` and it worked! Thank you very much, I must have overlooked it in the documentation. Now the curves move and change with the rest of the animation. Should I add it as an answer to this question or is it enough that it is in the comments?

Comment: @itypewithmyhands Just to clarify for potential future use, what exactly is a cluster handle? I could only find a cluster deformer (https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-CharacterAnimation/files/GUID-B7C96FEA-C415-4927-8E02-396F0E837DE2-htm.html) is it just two names for the same thing or is it something different?

Comment: Yeah that cluster deformer is what I was referring to, just using a the wrong terminology. I'll add an answer to this question based on our comment thread, so future Googlers can find the solution a bit easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, OP's issue was solved by specifying that `control points` should also be keyed:

```py
# Original code
cmds.setKeyframe(vectorCurve, time=i)

# Becomes
cmds.setKeyframe(vectorCurve, time=i, controlPoints=True)
```